# Отображение данных из связанных таблиц в TableView JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Возможно ли вывести в TableView поля из разных классов-сущностей?

Например: у меня имеются два класса сущностей `Person(String name, Car car)` и `Car(int id,String model)`, данные заполняются из БД.

Нужно в один `TableView` вывести поля "name" и "model", то есть поля из разных классов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты только создашь свой класс, который у тебя внутри себя будет содержать и `Person` и `Car`. Или из персон будет доступен `Car`. Если у тебя эти 2 класса никак не связаны, то никак - таблица в `javafx` может отображать данные лишь от одного класса.

**Update.**
Хотя ты можешь сделать так, чтобы таблица у тебя отображала класс `Person`, и для колонки model  ( к примеру) переопределить `TableCell` - в реализации будешь брать для данного `Person` его `Car` и выводить на экран.

**UPDATE2**

```
carColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(p.getValue().getCar().toString()));
```

**p.getValue** вернет тебе ссылку на текущий элемент в таблице

**p.getValue().getCar()** вернет тебе машину.

Если у тебя `carColumn<Person, String>` объявлен так, то тебе надо будет из объекта `p.getValue().getCar()` сделать строку, если у тебя колонка объявлена как `carColumn<Person, Car>`, то можно будет просто оставить `p.getValue().getCar()`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я немного неправильно описал проблему. Класс Person содержит не id_car, а поле car типа Car. Как мне замапить столбец таблицы на поле "model"?
Что-то вроде:
`carColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("car.model"));`

Comment: обновил ответ, смотри UPDATE2

Comment: Спасибо большое, это работает.
В моём случае это будет выглядеть так:
`carColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(p.getValue().getCar().getModel));`